# conditional median in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, median

I want to calculate a conditional median.

The formula =MEDIAN(K3851:K4792;$O3851:$O4792) works.
The step I cannot make is the one where the calculation
is restricted to when K<1. It seems easy enough, but I get
the error code "#NAME?".

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It's an error code, the correct response would be a figure, say 0,8973.

I for example tried =MEDIAN.IF(K3851:K4792;"<1";$03851:$04792).

Comment: Okay. But what should I do? It is possible to give formulas for calculating conditional median, isn't it?

Comment: Are you trying to say if column K <1 then process the value in column O or are you trying to say process all of the values in column K that are less than 1 as well as all of the values in column O?

Comment: if column K <1 then process the value in column O

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **array formula¹** to set up the condition. The array formula will pick up blank cells so you will have to add a condition to discard them as well.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(K3851:K4792<1; IF(K3851:K4792<>""; $O3851:$O4792)))
```

### **PROOF**

### [image: MEDIAN.IF array formula]

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, but the error is at least a different one now. ########. There are no blank cells though, so that isn't the explanation.

Comment: I would beg to differ. I've added a proof that shows the array formula result vs a standard [MEDIAN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MEDIAN-function-D0916313-4753-414C-8537-CE85BDD967D2) that lists the available values. They return the same results. [edit] The #### may be because you simply have not widened the column enough to show the result.

Comment: You might also want to check if the formula's cell is formatted as time or date. You cannot have a negative time or date and Excel will display ###### in the cell. Use General or any of the number formats and you should be OK.